# Tensorboard __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'purge_orphaned_data'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Running tensorboard for first time in a new VM and I end up with this error at tensorboard init(). Thanks for the help.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/sarath/virtualenvs/tensorflow/bin/tensorboard", line 9, in module> load_entry_point('tensorflow==0.7.1', 'console_scripts', 'tensorboard')()


  File "/home/sarath/virtualenvs/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py", line 82, in main
    purge_orphaned_data=FLAGS.purge_orphaned_data)

TypeError: __ init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'purge_orphaned_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

TensorBoard developer here. I'm quite confused how this happened, because while the purge_orphaned_data flag exists in [master](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py), it doesn't exist in [r0.7.1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v0.7.1/tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/tensorboard.py). Actually, the file path tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.py doesn't exist in 0.7.1 (it is in tensorboard/backend/tensorboard.py in 0.7.1).

So it looks like somehow you got an installation that mixes r0.7.1 but also files from master. Could you please file a Github issue on TensorFlow with a repro on how you got into this state?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As you said the versions were mixed up, I had two versions of tensorboard one within virtualenv and one outisde in /usr/bin - uninstalling the one within virtualenv solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I deleted "purge_orphaned_data=FLAGS.purge_orphaned_data" and it worked.